# Autofac equivalent of Unity's InjectionFactory

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, autofac

I need to translate the following Unity snippet to Autofac implementation:

```
        container.RegisterType<IMyThing>(
            new TransientLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IMyThingProvider>().GetTheThing()));
```

What's the equivalent of [InjectionFactory](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.Injection.InjectionFactory.html)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to use a [lambda registration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#lambda-expression-components):

```cs
container.Register(ctxt => ctxt.Resolve<IMyThingProvider>().GetTheThing())
         .As<IMyThing>();
```